# How can i take the data between two line in a text file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, text

I have a complicated text format output file named DATA_out (like the example below downside) and i want to take between two line (for example values and total) data inside the file and save as a csv. I made a start line with user input and end line. When my code running it knows where do writing start but i cant import the ending line ('total'). I just need add `start_line` and `end_line` to `re.compile`.

Do you have any suggestions for take data between two line with USER INPUT? Here what i have.

```
DATA_out file
      values
    DATA_LINE 1
    DATA_LINE 2
    DATA_LINE 3
    DATA_LINE 4
total
```

---

```
# Spyder Editor (Python 3.7)
import pandas as pd
import re

start_line = input('Starting:')
end_line = 'total' # end point.

with open('DATA_out.txt','r') as file:
    input = file.read()

rexp = re.compile(start_line,re.DOTALL) # need to add between start and end
match = rexp.search(input)
result = '' if match == None else match.group(1)
with open('NEW_FILE.txt','w') as file:
    file.write(result)
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: you could split it in two jobs: (1) read lines till you get line with `values`, (2) read and keep lines till you get line with `total`

Comment: using normal string function you could find `values` and `total` and use its positions to slice text - `text[values_pos+len("values"):total_pos]`

Comment: with regex you should use something like `values(.*)total` to get string between `values` and `total`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regex you can use `'values(.*)total'` or with `'\n'` - `'values\n(.*)\ntotal'`

```
text = '''DATA_out file
      values
    DATA_LINE 1
    DATA_LINE 2
    DATA_LINE 3
    DATA_LINE 4
total
'''

import re

result = re.search('values(.*)total', text, re.DOTALL)

if result:
    print(result[1])
    #print(result.group(1))
```

---

Without `regex` you can use `find()` to find positions of `values` and `total` separatelly, ad then slice it with `text[start:end]`

```
text = '''DATA_out file
      values
    DATA_LINE 1
    DATA_LINE 2
    DATA_LINE 3
    DATA_LINE 4
total
'''

start = text.find('values')
end = text.find('total', start)

if start > -1 and end > -1:
    start += len("values")  
    print(text[start:end])
```

---

If you want to read from file line by line.

I use `io.StringIO()` to simulate file

```
text = '''DATA_out file
      values
    DATA_LINE 1
    DATA_LINE 2
    DATA_LINE 3
    DATA_LINE 4
total
'''

import io

#f = open("input.txt")
f = io.StringIO(text)

lines = []

# read till you find line with 'values'
for line in f:
    if 'values' in line:
        break

# read till you find line with 'values'
for line in f:
    if 'total' in line:
        break
    lines.append(line)
else: # it is `for/else`, not `if/else`
    #if not found `total` (so there was no `break`) then clear list
    lines = []    

if lines:
    print("".join(lines))
```